# Objects and forces: air resistance

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, forces, air

A force always works between two objects. When we are talking about air resistance acting on a skydiver for example, would air be considered the second objects besides the skydiver?

Comment: you are vague in saying a force acts between two objects. anyway in your question, the utility of describing air as a second object depends on what problem do you need to exactly solve, i.e what approximation/simplification you are willing to make in the context of a specific problem..

Answer (score 1):

As Nogueira stated, the air is made up of more than one particle. If the idea you're using is that a force occurs between two objects, then you'd have to treat each air molecule as an individual object, and you'd have many, many forces, each between the skydiver (who you could treat as a single body) and an individual air molecule. Of course, this gets messy and is computationally impossible, but in a strictly conceptual context, this is correct.

If you had to do anything computational with this, it would be much wiser to move to a fluid dynamics interpretation. This would treat the air more collectively, relying on large-number statistics to give you a total sort of resistance force on the skydiver.

Answer (score 0):

Yes. The air is a [gas](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gas) made by a lot of particles. The air resistence takes the energy from the skydiver and transform into [heat](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heat). In other words, the molecules that made up the gas hits the skydiver, getting with some [kinetic energy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kinetic_energy) of the skydiver.